# Make some objects invisible when clicked on, only using HTML and CSS, without JS or jQuery

Tags: html, css

So we're a group of three that have our first assignment in IT. We're supposed to make a simple game or just a website with some basic HTML and CSS (no JS), preferably with animations. We have decided to make a game where your cursor is Homer Simpson, and he's trying to eat the donuts in the kitchen.

The basis for this is a background image of the kitchen room, some donut images and the image for the mouse cursor. The donuts are multiple PNGs with the same screen-size as the background-image.

So far we've managed to create a working cursor, background-image and placing the donuts. Our problem though, is that we can't figure out how to make the donuts invisible when clicked upon.

Below is the code from both our HTML and CSS documents.

```css
body {
    height: 100vh;
    cursor: url('../images/homer2.png'), auto;
}

body:active {
    height: 100vh;
    cursor: url('../images/homer-eat2.png'), auto;
}
.kitchen {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.donut1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: visible;
}
.donut1:active{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.donut2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.donut3{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.donut4{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.donut5{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.images {
    position: relative; 
    left: 0; 
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Eat the donuts!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/spillside.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div images>
        <img src="../images/background-page2-new.png" class="kitchen" draggable="false" usemap="#img-map">>
        <img src="../images/donut-1.png" class="donut1" draggable="false">
        <img src="../images/donut-2.png" class="donut2" draggable="false"> 
        <img src="../images/donut-3.png" class="donut3" draggable="false"> 
        <img src="../images/donut-4.png" class="donut4" draggable="false">
        <img src="../images/donut-5.png" class="donut5" draggable="false">     
    </div>       
</body>
</html>
```

So far we've only tried to make donut1 disappear, as we found it a bit pointless to copy paste that code before it actually works. Donut1 is the one at the table.

Below are some images of it for reference:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzyAc.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCIZd.png

Comment: using :active or :focus will, re-appear the images, you can easily do this with the help radio buttons. plain and simple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can achieve the result you want with the help of radio buttons.
its a nice and clean trick to hide something only with HMTL, CSS. (no JS)
Here I have setup a small example for you.

Follow this in your game, Put your Donut image in label and hide it when related input checked using CSS as I did, try to run this snippet and then click on d1, d2 text.

**Note: if you want to re-appear your Image on click again, use Checkbox instead of radio.**

```css
input {display: none;}
input:checked + label {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section>
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="donut1">
  <label for="donut1">Donut 1</label> 
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="donut2">
  <label for="donut2">Donut 2</label> 
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="donut3">
  <label for="donut3">Donut 3</label> 
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="donut4">
  <label for="donut4">Donut 4</label> 
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: That kind of works. Only problem now is that you have to press a button on the side of the page to hide a donut, I'd like that button to be invisible and placed on the donut.
pic: https://i.imgur.com/TGIEZZv.png
code i used: https://pastebin.com/RjQwjwk7

Comment: You dont need to keep them side of your page, as per your code you are using the donut images, so just make them position absolute and place them on different positions, I can help you more if you will create a codepen or fiddle with the same example.

Comment: I've tried making them absolute now, but they dont seem to disappear when I click (those buttons are also gone). Tried to create a fiddle for the first time: https://jsfiddle.net/b43cxurw/#&togetherjs=VlvaaADBfL

Also uploaded some of the workfiles to drive: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1VAH-DvdD3Pm_Rl3OnAzBSeU3rUNW2SKH?usp=sharing

Comment: I have updated your fiddle as per your need, enjoy coding, https://jsfiddle.net/mgn39rye/